# Excel conditional formatting based on time differences

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want cell `D` that has `mm/dd/year hh:mm am/pm` to highlight if cell `C` with the same date and time format is two hours more or less than the date and time in `D`

Comment: This can be done with conditional formatting. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
    A         B
-------------------
1| Time 1    Time 2
2| 8:00 AM   9:00 AM
3| 10:00 AM  3:00 PM
```

1 Select values in column B

2 Home -> Conditional Formatting -> New Rule

3 Select **Use a formula to determine which cells to format**

4 enter formula `=abs(A2-B2)*24>2`

5 Click format button and select the format and click OK.